# How to navigate between screens in react without usage of libraries like react router

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to know if is possible to navigate between screens, using like a context api, or something else, where I can get the "navigateTo" function in any component without passing by props. And of course, without the cycle dependency problem.

Example with the cycle dependency problem

NavigateContext.tsx:

```
import React, { createContext, useMemo, useReducer } from 'react'

import { Home } from './pages/Home'

interface NavigateProps {
  navigateTo: (screenName: string) => void
}

export const navigateContext = createContext({} as NavigateProps)

const reducer = (state: () => JSX.Element, action: { type: string }) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'home':
      return Home

    default:
      throw new Error('Page not found')
  }
}

export function NavigateContextProvider() {
  const [Screen, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, Home)

  const value = useMemo(() => {
    return {
      navigateTo: (screenName: string) => {
        dispatch({ type: screenName })
      },
    }
  }, [])

  return (
    <navigateContext.Provider value={value}>
      <Screen />
    </navigateContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

Home.tsx:

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect } from 'react'
import { Flex, Text } from '@chakra-ui/react'
import { navigateContext } from '../NavigateContext'

export function Home() {
  const { navigateTo } = useContext(navigateContext)
  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      navigateTo('home')
    }, 2000)
  }, [])

  return (
    <Flex>
      <Text>Home</Text>
    </Flex>
  )
}
```

Comment: You can probably use dynamic import for this: https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html#import. Return promise with imported component in your reducer. But still the question is why do you want to avoid router usage which was designed specifically for this purpose?

Comment: I already tried use the lazy method from react, but still got the "cycle dependency" problem :c
Probably I will give up on the end of the day and use the router, it's just a research, but thanks anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is possible, but you'll need to maintain the list of string view names independently from your mapping of them to their associated components in order to avoid circular dependencies (what you call "the cycle dependency problem" in your question):

> Note, I created this in the TS Playground (which doesn't support modules AFAIK), so I annotated module names in comments. You can separate them into individual files to test/experiment.

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&ssl=71&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbwFBzgEwKYDMCGBXAG3hwGc4AlDHAYxgBoU5qoqYMBhCAOzYA97GeEh258BqIRgCiWLBloMJwgMowcbRXBgBPMBjgARYCTDrqAC0069FKrSkEMIDDyu79yjDFXqMAQVpgbgYAXzgsKAgQOAByFhoYGIBuJFSAegzMrLgAN2AMAHcSADoYEiQMuCkcjChtLVB9bQg8OBw0NDSWEAgattz8grhgLjhmvCg2sDA6MZaYggI4LgwMNC0IODwwNF8tc2M2qCgcbQAuJAxeSFgmbhJ4PMKyAF44AG0Y8yiMGNmYnAAIxaiQAum0yNR7jAUlcbvBrPoAGqDOBvREQLADZ7vLh4ECA2qglKXa7QBHuOAowqcHhXeBvZCoYQwakFM6GYymGAWAA8nm8ajYARgQS4vLZAD5JSkQiS4eS7lwHtiCrSxGimPE2Or6QAKBBhUhUwa6-gAShJFSyNrgAAkfqVypVQPDEKqzfAwhEorFimknkVkqkFbcsHguIFuPafnA9eaOZQEg4nC54EylSqECy2WE3pJPXrA57LYJhDI5LQ9fG0ZLchBgOsWQAVRog6vm2twHODPVfH4xc2zABMAAZx0OPqDS6gWDAJqM9by0MAcpKHc5eWkV2vSyFUtabZk4H5gXgYE7rcNwIqEB7RPS4N7ItEYv7AyRg6S3eHI6Lo6eIJxgmtjJo4zg8IgjBQsq6Y9oUeZbMIhbFg+FopLOXgLnGjCoMuq6SrhqBwPha6AeeW47oRxHEbygLnjA0bcOwBDANQADWLwIDWLx1vBBR9t8ziDiEkoAOKbBuGBbvRMCMVw1G0duBGMHuB5HtknoAAqRHkmBQE6vBXq6t6oXS-CzIiJoIeEL5+gGgyfikLo3rcCBSc+vpvmkUnBi5boIORMCea+-pBX5aTXgFUg8iF9kxdQX6VNUtT1KKzhzK07SdN0vT6DgqrDKM4yTDg0yzOMCxLCsawbFsOx7DABxkBAgIAFbyDAFwwSqgYALJlYm8jQGgEqDLMPF1km9jgWmdaMowQkYByUmaECIIckFmiVF41AcgloQkr+UajGyOm9I2tTAVBqA9fA7yBrM-HgvmKhCtJUqCQOM6ZvA7ATCwPBspq-VlQ9gzEqkmHzlAi5EbyZliMU516VdOQ4AQeAYFx2ZeLmolEXh-3HGmwNpIpeEOTSaEXijl1QIpalAA)

```ts
import {
  default as React,
  createContext,
  useContext,
  useEffect,
  useState,
  type Dispatch,
  type ReactElement,
  type SetStateAction,
} from 'react';


////////// views.ts
// Every time you add/remove a view in your app, you'll need to update this array:
export const views = ['home', 'about'] as const;
export type View = typeof views[number];

export type ViewContext = {
  setView: Dispatch<SetStateAction<View>>;
};

export const viewContext = createContext({} as ViewContext);


////////// Home.ts
// import { viewContext } from './views';

export function Home (): ReactElement {
  const {setView} = useContext(viewContext);
  useEffect(() => void setTimeout(() => setView('home'), 2000), []);
  return (<div>Home</div>);
}


////////// About.ts
// import { viewContext } from './views';

export function About (): ReactElement {
  const {setView} = useContext(viewContext);
  return (
    <div>
      <div>About</div>
      <button onClick={() => setView('home')}>Go Home</button>
    </div>
  );
}


////////// ContextProvider.tsx
// import {viewContext, type View} from './views';
// import {Home} from './Home';
// import {About} from './About';
// import {Etc} from './Etc';

// Every time you add/remove a view in your app, you'll need to update this object:
const viewMap: Record<View, () => ReactElement> = {
  home: Home,
  about: About,
  // etc: Etc,
};

function ViewProvider () {
  const [view, setView] = useState<View>('home');
  const CurrentView = viewMap[view];

  return (
    <viewContext.Provider value={{setView}}>
      <CurrentView />
    </viewContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for all your effort, this looks amazing and solved the circular dependency in ContextProvider.tsx, but not in the Home.tsx
https://imgur.com/InN0sc2

Comment: If you wanna talk about it, we can meet at discord, my user is Rashid#2420

Comment: @LucasMessias Here's a temporary server invite link: https://discord.gg/rNVJFwhh